# MLIR intermediate representation of a tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, llvm-ir

Can anyone guide me the process of converting a tensorflow model in to MLIR. I'm using:
`iree-import-tf saved_model/ -o output.mlir`
Where I've generated the saved model direcotory using:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
# Download the pre-trained model from TensorFlow Hub
model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/classification/4"
model = hub.load(model_url)
# Save the model in the SavedModel format
tf.saved_model.save(model, "saved_model/")
```

But when I use mlip-opt view-ir on the generated output.mlir using iree-import-tf, it gives me no output:

```
./mlir-opt --print-ir output.mlir
// -----// IR Dump //----- //
module {
}
module {
}
```

Can anyone guide me how can I get the MLIR intermediate representation of a model.

Above is the solution I've tried